# ActiveAdmin update has_many field error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I add to active admin page for table `events`

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        # ....
    end

    f.has_many :category_for_events, :allow_destroy => true do |d|
        d.inputs do
            d.input :event_category
        end
    end
end
```

Also I add this row to my model `Event`

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :category_for_events
```

It's looks like ok. But when I try save data I get error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category_for_events_attributes
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to add the following to your `Event` model:

```
attr_accessible :category_for_events_attributes
```

See the [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) docs.

Comment: Get the error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: event_category_id`

Answer (score -1):

ActiveAdmin.register ...... do

permit_params :category_for_events_attributes => [:id, other fields ,:_destroy]

form do |f|
end

end